# TypeError: Required argument 'name' (pos 1) not found

Tags: python, gdb

I am getting following error when i try to run my first python script for gdb

```
TypeError: Required argument 'name' (pos 1) not found
```

my script

```
import gdb
class HelloWorld (gdb.Command):
           """Greet the whole world."""

def __init__ (self):
           super (HelloWorld, self).__init__ ("hello-world", gdb.COMMAND_USER)


def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
           print "Hello, World!"

HelloWorld ()
```

i am just trying to learn python scripting for gdb

error

```
(gdb) source firstScript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gdbtest2.py", line 12, in <module>
    HelloWorld ()
TypeError: Required argument 'name' (pos 1) not found
```

Comment: You have to first create the instance of the class HelloWorld...You cant run the class...

Comment: i believe it is created by gdb while loading

Comment: I don't think so...Also, the methods you've written should be indented to be a part of the class.

Comment: Hai raman : i have followed the format provided by gdb , i will change my intdentation and check , thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Raman : it worked post indentation

Answer (score 1):

I have a simillar problem

```py
import gdb

class Open(gdb.Command):
    """test open"""
    def __inti__(self):
        super().__inti__('_open', gdb.COMMAND_USER)

    def invoke(self, args, from_tty):
        argv = gdb.string_to_argv(args)
        print(argv)

Open()
```

bug is the typing error of  "__init__"", I know this is stupid, but I just did it. maybe it will help someone else.